ethool -m text output incomplete, but complete as hex
We're struggling with reading Laser rx/tx levels from a 10G SFP" in a Supermicro server.
ethtool -m (or --modinfo or --dump-module-eeprom) is supposed to deliver this info, and it does work... somewhat-ish.
QUESTION:

What could cause ethtool to provide the full eeprom data as hex, but to (apparently) truncate text output?
Are there any known alternatives to ethtool?
Any other known parsers/converters we could feed ethtool's hex output into?

Supermicro Box (SYS-110D-8C-FRAN8TP), Ubuntu, Intel NIC, ice kernel module.
$ uname -a
Linux s01-chgva1-evrw 5.15.0-102-generic #112-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 5 16:50:32 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS \n \l

and
$ ethtool --version
ethtool version 5.16

and
$ modinfo ice 
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-102-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ice/ice.ko
firmware:       intel/ice/ddp/ice.pkg
license:        GPL v2
description:    Intel(R) Ethernet Connection E800 Series Linux Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     E7701886AAC16AD41A71F0E
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000151Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
[...]
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001591sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ice
vermagic:       5.15.0-102-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        2E:23:16:41:BE:E2:75:E4:E8:36:37:AE:9D:F0:67:4D:5A:8B:52:0F
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      4F:BE:D8:FA:E5:7C:3D:AC:99:43:2A:10:33:35:A3:4D:BE:95:66:DA:
                [...]
                E2:2F:13:EC:31:01:FE:A8:F2:C2:
                CB:05:DB:4B:4C:D6:76:C2:92:01:FD:D0
parm:           debug:netif level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)

On another supermicro box with ubuntu, ethtool -m delivers full info from the very same SFP+, see at the bottom.
Text Output from ethtool -m. That can't be complete, and unfortunately the interesting bits are missing.
$ sudo ethtool --dump-module-eeprom enp137s0f0
        Identifier                                : 0x03 (SFP)
        Extended identifier                       : 0x04 (GBIC/SFP defined by 2-wire interface ID)
        Connector                                 : 0x07 (LC)
        Transceiver codes                         : 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x22 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00
        Transceiver type                          : 10G Ethernet: 10G Base-LR
        Transceiver type                          : FC: intermediate distance (I)
        Transceiver type                          : FC: Longwave laser (LC)
        Transceiver type                          : FC: Single Mode (SM)
        Encoding                                  : 0x06 (64B/66B)
        BR, Nominal                               : 10300MBd
        Rate identifier                           : 0x00 (unspecified)
        Length (SMF,km)                           : 10km
        Length (SMF)                              : 10000m
        Length (50um)                             : 0m
        Length (62.5um)                           : 0m
        Length (Copper)                           : 0m
        Length (OM3)                              : 0m
        Laser wavelength                          : 1310nm
        Vendor name                               : FS
        Vendor OUI                                : 00:00:00
        Vendor PN                                 : SFP-10GLR-31
        Vendor rev                                : 
        Option values                             : 0x00 0x1a
        Option                                    : RX_LOS implemented
        Option                                    : TX_FAULT implemented
        Option                                    : TX_DISABLE implemented
        BR margin, max                            : 14%
        BR margin, min                            : 88%
        Vendor SN                                 : G2208169504
        Date code                                 : 220831

We spent quite some hours in swapping modules (same series) through various servers, NICs and cisco switches and got mixed results - sometimes full output (see below), sometimes truncated at Date Code (see above).
However, on the main box, somewhat surprisingly, ethtool -m  hex on shows the expected 2 pages of 256 bytes as per SFF-8472 https://members.snia.org/document/dl/25916 (cf. clause 9.8), and nonzero values in bytes 102 to 105 of the second page.
So the data is there, ethtool can retrieve it, but won't parse/display it for some reason - but why?
$ sudo ethtool --dump-module-eeprom enp137s0f0 hex on 
Offset          Values
------          ------
0x0000:         03 04 07 20 00 00 00 22 00 01 00 06 67 00 0a 64 
0x0010:         00 00 00 00 46 53 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 
0x0020:         20 20 20 20 00 00 00 00 53 46 50 2d 31 30 47 4c 
0x0030:         52 2d 33 31 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 05 1e 00 95 
0x0040:         00 1a 0e 58 47 32 32 30 38 31 36 39 35 30 34 20 
0x0050:         20 20 20 20 32 32 30 38 33 31 20 20 68 f0 03 37 
0x0060:         00 00 08 14 a3 bf 9f 74 e0 4b 30 bb ba 21 df e8 
0x0070:         2f bf cc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f a7 65 af 
0x0080:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0090:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x00a0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x00b0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x00c0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x00d0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x00e0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x00f0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0100:         4b 00 fb 00 46 00 00 00 8d cc 74 04 87 5a 7a 76 
0x0110:         d6 d8 01 f4 c3 50 03 e8 57 73 02 5b 2b d4 05 ea 
0x0120:         57 73 00 91 2b d4 01 6b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0130:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0140:         00 00 00 00 3f 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
0x0150:         01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 6d 
0x0160:         21 8e 82 44 34 e6*16 38*07 0a*00 00 00 00 00 00  0x1638 | 0x070a
0x0170:         00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 01 
0x0180:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0190:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x01a0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x01b0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x01c0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x01d0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x01e0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x01f0:         00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

The values being reported here are 16 bit unsigned integers, as steps of 0.1µW:
TX:  Bytes 102 and 103   0x1638  568,8µW  roughly   -2.5 dBm
RX:  Bytes 104 and 105   0x070a  108,2µW  roughly   -7.5 dBm

... which is perfectly plausible for the situation these values were captured from: Two SFPs from the same vendor and same series, a 3m cable and a -5dB attenuator in each fibre strand.
The same module in another Linux Box (also Ubuntu, also Supermicro, but with ixgbe instead of ice; details of kernel, module or ethtool hex dump unavailable at this time.
# ethtool -m enp1s0f1
    Identifier                                : 0x03 (SFP)
    Extended identifier                       : 0x04 (GBIC/SFP defined by 2-wire interface ID)
    Connector                                 : 0x07 (LC)
    Transceiver codes                         : 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x22 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00
    Transceiver type                          : 10G Ethernet: 10G Base-LR
    Transceiver type                          : FC: intermediate distance (I)
    Transceiver type                          : FC: Longwave laser (LC)
    Transceiver type                          : FC: Single Mode (SM)
    Encoding                                  : 0x06 (64B/66B)
    BR, Nominal                               : 10300MBd
    Rate identifier                           : 0x00 (unspecified)
    Length (SMF,km)                           : 10km
    Length (SMF)                              : 10000m
    Length (50um)                             : 0m
    Length (62.5um)                           : 0m
    Length (Copper)                           : 0m
    Length (OM3)                              : 0m
    Laser wavelength                          : 1310nm
    Vendor name                               : FS
    Vendor OUI                                : 00:00:00
    Vendor PN                                 : SFP-10GLR-31
    Vendor rev                                : 
    Option values                             : 0x00 0x1a
    Option                                    : RX_LOS implemented
    Option                                    : TX_FAULT implemented
    Option                                    : TX_DISABLE implemented
    BR margin, max                            : 14%
    BR margin, min                            : 88%
    Vendor SN                                 : G2208169504
    Date code                                 : 220831
    Optical diagnostics support               : Yes
    Laser bias current                        : 27.648 mA
    Laser output power                        : 0.5673 mW / -2.46 dBm
    Receiver signal average optical power     : 0.2037 mW / -6.91 dBm
    Module temperature                        : 35.80 degrees C / 96.44 degrees F
    Module voltage                            : 3.3300 V
    Alarm/warning flags implemented           : Yes
    Laser bias current high alarm             : Off
    Laser bias current low alarm              : Off
    Laser bias current high warning           : Off
    Laser bias current low warning            : Off
    Laser output power high alarm             : Off
    Laser output power low alarm              : Off
    Laser output power high warning           : Off
    Laser output power low warning            : Off
    Module temperature high alarm             : Off
    Module temperature low alarm              : Off
    Module temperature high warning           : Off
    Module temperature low warning            : Off
    Module voltage high alarm                 : Off
    Module voltage low alarm                  : Off
    Module voltage high warning               : Off
    Module voltage low warning                : Off
    Laser rx power high alarm                 : Off
    Laser rx power low alarm                  : Off
    Laser rx power high warning               : Off
    Laser rx power low warning                : Off
    Laser bias current high alarm threshold   : 110.000 mA
    Laser bias current low alarm threshold    : 1.000 mA
    Laser bias current high warning threshold : 100.000 mA
    Laser bias current low warning threshold  : 2.000 mA
    Laser output power high alarm threshold   : 2.2387 mW / 3.50 dBm
    Laser output power low alarm threshold    : 0.0603 mW / -12.20 dBm
    Laser output power high warning threshold : 1.1220 mW / 0.50 dBm
    Laser output power low warning threshold  : 0.1514 mW / -8.20 dBm
    Module temperature high alarm threshold   : 75.00 degrees C / 167.00 degrees F
    Module temperature low alarm threshold    : -5.00 degrees C / 23.00 degrees F
    Module temperature high warning threshold : 70.00 degrees C / 158.00 degrees F
    Module temperature low warning threshold  : 0.00 degrees C / 32.00 degrees F
    Module voltage high alarm threshold       : 3.6300 V


The most likely reason is a driver glitch - possibly ice reports DDM as absent with ethtool just believing that, without verifying the raw data. Would be interesting to see the Linux kernel module interface to see what information a NIC driver provides.

To (partially) answer my own questions:

Are there any known alternatives to ethtool?

None really needed. ethtool -m <interface> hex on can provide the data; just need to extract it.

Any other known parsers/converters we could feed ethtool's hex output into?

There's always brainware:

Find bytes 102-105 of the second 256bytes page of the hex dump (line 0x0160 starts with byte #96)
Read bytes 102-103 as one 16 bit unsigned integer
use any tool to convert hex to decimal (Windows' own calc.exe will do nicely)
divide value by 10 to get the optical TX power in µW
decimal-shift to mW, and do 10 * log(P-in-mW) to get TX power in dBm (or use one of the online converters available)

and..

repeat with bytes 104 and 105 to get RX power

Not really cool, but it does the trick in times of need.
